# Errors when adding podfile into a salesforce IOS SDK sample app

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I added a podfile into the VFConnector salesforce ios sample app from https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS.  Now the app can't be compiled anymore and complaining

```
  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' 
  pod "M2DWebViewController"
```

Comment: What is the full text of the error?

Comment: It's coming out from appDelegate+SalesforceHybridSDK.h, the content is /Users/alexwong/Documents/Ios/SalesforceApps/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/shared/hybrid/AppDelegate+SalesforceHybridSDK.h:26:9: 'SalesforceHybridSDK/SFHybridViewController.h' file not found, /Users/alexwong/Documents/Ios/SalesforceApps/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/shared/hybrid/AppDelegate+SalesforceHybridSDK.m:27:9: In file included from /Users/alexwong/Documents/Ios/SalesforceApps/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/shared/hybrid/AppDelegate+SalesforceHybridSDK.m:27:

Comment: And does that file exist in your project?

Comment: Yes. it's in the shared folder and reused by different sample apps. Once I run "pod install", it starts having this error.

Comment: After you run `pod install`, make sure you are opening the `.xcworkspace` not the `.xcodeproj`.

Comment: Which on should I run? The SalesforceMobileSDK.xcworkspace ? or the .xcworkspace of this project? The error comes out if I run SalesforceMobileSDK.xcworkspace. However, I think it wouldn't make sense to run the project.xcworkspace as it'd miss SDK files.

Comment: Your app should only have one `.xcworkspace` and it should be the one generated by `pod install`. It sounds like you've added an extra workspace and/or project that does not belong.

Comment: If you look at https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS, "SalesforceMobileSDK.xcworkspace" is the one to run all the sample apps. Then I put a podfile under VFConnect and "pod install" generates "VFConnect.xcworkspace".  Anything wrong with it?

Comment: They are providing a sample workspace file that includes their sample apps. You certainly will not want to use their workspace file, nor their sample apps, if you are adding the SDK to your own app.

Comment: Right. I won't use them. All I'm seeking is an easy way to put together the SDK and pods. This is why I tried forceios create to add the SDK and then put podfile in but that one doesn't allow us to edit the SDK, which I do need. What'd you recommend?

Comment: Again, forceios is not suitable if you want to make edits to the library. Add your podfile to your app as normal, then install the SDK as described in the repo's readme.

Comment: is this readme you're talking about https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS-Distribution/blob/master/README.md?